# Entity Graph generation for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, graph, entity-relationship

What are the options for generating a graphical representation of my entities and their relationships in Google App Engine?

I'm thinking about the lines of what DbVisualizer can do for relational DBs...

Comment: Problem with visualizing GAE Datastore Entities is entity of same 'kind' may have completely different properties(fields) for different entity instances. Same property-name may have different 'Type' in different instances. There is no entity blueprint (metdata).